# Is post by AJAX with prepared statement safe from sql injection?

Tags: php, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I have a form and post to `file.php` by AJAX like this:

```html
<?php
    $sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO warna SET id_warna='', nm_warna=? ");
    $sql->bind_param("s", $nm_warna);
    $sql->execute();
?>
```

Is it safe? Or what must I do to make it safe?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for [a code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah it is safe.

Prepared statements and parameterized queries are used to prevent SQL injections.

You've used the same thing, and that should avoid any user to play with your SQL queries.

[PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) is a better option, which also speeds up your SQL queries.